# Top internet search result leads to bad SO question

Tags: discussion, search, google

The top Google search result for "python convert utf8 to integer" lead me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625627/python3-convert-unicode-string-to-int-representation):

This was closed as a low quality question.  Should we care?  If so, is it feasible to automatically steer search bots toward better Q/A?

Comment: What exactly is "bad" about the question other than it being low quality? Are the answers wrong or outdated? is there a better question on SO that answer's this question? (if so, is there anything we can do to improve it's ranking, such as upvoting it?)

Comment: @Kevin, Maybe these fall into two categories.  "Bad" question that provide value vs. "Bad" questions that do not.

Comment: I think in general as far as those two cases go is bad that do not provide value should be deleted, and the other should be improved and possibly re-opened.

Comment: Would be nice if Google could interpret the voting at SO, not in the cards.   The basics are still intact, if you ask the wrong question then you're going to get the wrong answer.  And you can definitely tell it was the wrong question when you look at what you got.

Comment: Certainly. You just go ahead and fire that email off to Google and ask them to quit turning up that question in their search results. :-) Seriously, are you asking why Google isn't paying attention to whether a question is open or closed and it's vote count when providing search results?

Comment: @Ken White,  I think "automatically steer search bots" means I don't expect Google to lift a finger, i.e. something in Robots.txt perhaps.

Comment: In the general case, is there any real harm caused by low quality or closed questions turning up in Google search results?

Answer (score 8):

The question isn't exactly gold plated. It makes some interesting assertions and doesn't provide much in the way of showing effort. However, it is basically asking about using encoding which Martijn Pieters covers in an answer on that question.

The overall set of answers seem to contain useful information and there aren't any link only answers or anything bizarre.

I edited the question to hopefully improve the readability a little. It was not possible without hijacking it to include code or some sort of pseudo attempt at solving the problem so I mostly left it with the author's original intent.

As there have been a relatively low amount of views on this question in the past 3 years (4100) I do not think it is of utmost importance to worry about this question. However, as it stands it seems that it isn't doing much harm and does pose an answerable question within the scope of the site (although still lacking a direct attempt) and as a result I have voted to reopen it.